# Centering an outer div, 'text-align:center' not working as expected

Tags: css, html, centering

I have a section of content in a div, and this is currently centered to the left.  [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/79x2a/1/)

I tried adding a container div like:

```
<div style='text-align:center; width:100px;'>[content]</div>
```

But no luck.  Also tried this:

```
<div style='margin: 0px auto; width:100px;'>[content]</div>
```

Content is still left aligned.

This works, but I'd like to find the right way to do this with CSS:

```
<div style='width:100px;' align='center'>[content]</div>
```

Assistance appreciated.  I'm tempted to do this with tables, but I need to break out of old habits!

Comment: there's a lot of markup, css, and inline styles in your fiddle; it's a little hard to square up with your question. is it the `<div class="menu">` that you're looking to center?

Comment: I'm wanting to center the white area (with rounded edges).  I do not want to change alignment of anything in this area - just need the entire white section centered.

Comment: So that means you want `<div class="rounded-corners" style="width: 600px; background-color:#FFFFFF;">` to be centered? Or the content within it to be centered? Either way, you should be able to center the div with lateral margins of `auto` or the content with `text-align: center`, as many have pointed out below.

Comment: Should is the key word.  The problem is that text-align:center isn't working in my example.  This would be so much easier to lay out with tables, but I need to learn the right way.

Comment: `text-align` doesn't center divs... it centers text...

Comment: Here is a more simplified version of the same example:   http://jsfiddle.net/79x2a/7/

Comment: As I said on my answer down there: http://jsfiddle.net/79x2a/8/

Comment: You edited your answer before I saw it.  The updated answer works.

Comment: That's why I pointed you there =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you try to get the outer div centered respect to its parent (`body`in this case) you should set its lateral margins to auto:

```
body div{
    margin: auto;
}
```

as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/79x2a/5/)

Comment: @IlanBiala: woah, so helpful. What are you trying to center?

Comment: the div and not the content

Comment: Ok that works better.  Is this the best way of accomplishing what I want?  Does it meet "standards"?

Comment: As long as I know it's the best and more standard meeting way... and it's the one I've been using lately.

Comment: What if i want to add a bit margin on focus or hover?! (Kills the center alignment then) any solution?

Answer (score 3):

The tool to center a div is actually `margin: 0 auto;`.

Comment: center a div, but not it's content

Comment: what are you trying to center?

Comment: you can use it for content too

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the content with another `div` inside "rounded-corners'.

And write `style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;"` for this new div